# How to enable shortcodes in Child theme which is disabled by parent theme?

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

How to enable shortcodes in Child theme which is disabled by parent theme?

In parent theme, "gallery" shortcode is disabled by the following code.

```
add_shortcode('gallery', '__return_false');
```

How to enable it using a child theme? It is in a class file and I tried it by copying and removing this line on child theme folder but didn't work.

Comment: Why dont you enable it in the parent theme?

Comment: I'm customising the parent theme using child. Got the answer now. I'll post it.

Comment: Awesome, good job :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a high value for priority (low in action) (eg:150) and add it to init as shown below.

```
add_action('init', 'override_gallery', 150);

//Override gallery function
function override_gallery()
{
    //deactivate Theme function
    remove_shortcode('gallery', '__return_false'); //if __return_false is used in parent theme to disable this shortcode.
    //activate own function
    add_shortcode('gallery', 'gallery_shortcode'); 
}
```